# Google sheets importxml Facebook views not working

Tags: facebook, video, google-sheets, view

I've been having issues with this for a while. Basically I want to grab the view count from a Facebook video posts. I successfully did it with YouTube and it auto updates as views come in.

I've been using this code for the Facebook(video is an example)

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.facebook.com/greatbigstory/videos/1727744637527962/","//div[@class='_1vx9']")
```

and this gives me the views and the video name and the account it was posted under, which is what I want!

But my issue is that after 10 minutes, it randomly stops workings and gives me

> Error, imported content is empty

I have to then delete the code. Click off the cell than paste it again and it will re-load properly. But than quickly goes "offline" again.

If there's anybody out there that could help me that would be greatly appreciated! thank you!

Comment: This would be _scraping_ of Facebook pages, and that is not allowed, against their ToS. If you want any such data, you need to use their API.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! thank you!